# Why can the compiler not differentiate between double** and double*

Tags: c++, c, pointers, arguments

I have created two routines, one to sort a vector in-place:

```
void Sort(double** vector, unsigned int vectorLength) {
    //...
}
```

and one that returns a new array with the sorted result:

```
double* Sort(double* vector, unsigned int vectorLength) {
    //...
}
```

Later using the sort method:

```
double* test = new double[5];
//...
Sort(*test, 5);
```

I receive the compiler error that 'none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types.'

Is not the type double*, a pointer to a double, not fundamentally different to a double**, a pointer to a pointer to a double?

How is this not clear to the compiler?

Comment: the compiler is not a magical entity. it does exactly what you tell it, and in this case you are telling it something incorrect.

Comment: Aah, rookie error. I'm feeling like this question has very little value now...

Comment: Not to others, but it does to you. The first lesson for you is that you should not abuse overloading in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `test` has type `double*` and so `*double` has type `double`. Which means that you are attempting to pass `double` which matches neither `double*` nor `double**`.

One possibility is that you actually meant to create a sorted copy of the original array:

```
double* sorted = Sort(test, 5);
```

But I rather presume, since your call to `Sort` ignores the return value, that you meant to pass `&test` to sort in-place.

```
Sort(&test, 5);
```

However, that in itself indicates that your interface is badly designed. You would pass `&test` if you wanted the function to modify `test`. But you don't. You want the function to modify the array that `test` refers to. Your in-place sort function can, and should, be implemented by passing a parameter of type `double*`.

It is my opinion that you are abusing function overloading here. I would recommend that you choose a different design. I would use functions with different names.

Some other comments:

1. Use `size_t` for array lengths.
2. Use `const` to indicate that an input parameter shall not be modified.

Comment: Thanks David, the reference vs. dereference was exactly the problem. Then I see why you're saying the interface is badly designed, the first line of the implementation is to get the inner pointer and work on it. However you may be able to help me. The way I tend to set up these low-level operators is to have an in-place operator and a return-value operator side-by-side with the return-value version calling the in-place implementation. That is in .net. What is a good c++ equivalent to this structure that can still use overloading and not need ugly function names?

Comment: Additionally, what is the benefit of using size_t? I have seen it before but frankly it looks like some messy hangover from the past so have avoided it.

Comment: Before I go on, I wonder if any of this is necessary. Are you aware of `std::vector<T>` which is the standard container that fits your problem. Equivalent to `List<T>` in C#.

Comment: David, I'm working with an existing code base that uses both vectors and arrays so without a complete refactoring, I do need to work below the comfort of vectors.

Comment: size_t is the type used to measure lengths. It is used everywhere for that in C++.

Comment: And as for the other question, I think overloading is just wrong. You are talking about returning raw unmanaged pointers. That's something that you need to flag up load and clear to the programmer. There's no GC to clear up after you. So I would use different names. The fact that both input arrays are `double*` makes overloading not possible. Out of interest, could you show how you do this in C#?

Comment: Surely your suggestion that overloading is wrong isn't just because of the hairiness of the returned memory needing manual disposal. Overloading has other properties that are quite useful. To be honest I wish the language structure could use return type to differentiate between overloads and use the calling code's return type expectation with which to choose.

Comment: You could have `void sort(double* in, size_t len)` for the in-place and `void sort(const double* in, size_t len, double* &out)` for the sorted copy variant. I don't personally think I would choose that.

Answer (score 4):

You get the error because `*test` expression is neither `double*` nor `double**` - it's a `double`, with no asterisks.

Passing `test` without dereferencing it would have worked:

```
double* sorted = Sort(test, 5); // Invokes the second overload
```

Note that you can sort in place even if you pass a pointer. Using an overload for this that requires an artificial `&`, works but it makes your API counter-intuitive.

A better approach would be defining a method with the same set of parameters, but a different name, for example

```
double* Sort(double* vector, size_t vectorLength) {
    //...
}
void SortInPlace(double* vector, size_t vectorLength) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: That would be utterly pointless though. That's the overload that does not modify the data that was passed, and returns a new array. So your code leaks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right, OP does say "returns a new array with the sorted result"! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

It's very clear, but the expression `*test` when `test` has the type `double *` is the same as `test[0]`, i.e. it's a `double` and not a pointer at all.

Perhaps you meant `&test` to take the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`*test` goes directly to the value stored in that memory address. So, it goes to the `double` stored in the address `test`, which is a pointer to double.

So, you're passing a `double` value, not a pointer.

Your work would work with either of these two:

```
Sort(test, 5); // Passes a pointer to double.
```

or

```
Sort(&test, 5); // Gives you the address of test. Passes a pointer to a pointer to double.
```